# MessageBox.Show for Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, messagebox

I need a MessageBox.Show(), but with an extended functionality: the built-in messagebox for Windows Phone 7 won't show arbitrary buttons, just OK or cancel, I need for example YesNo as well. I need a Show method that will return only when the user clicks on a button. I tried to make my own messagebox as popup. The problem is that it is asynchronous as everything in the UI-thread in WP7, and I cannot block the UI-thread because the UI-thread is responsible for handling the button click events as well. I saw a ChildWindow example for WP7, but that was also asynchronous, I must have a Show() method that returns only when the user clicks. Any suggestions? Some kind of DoEvents() could help me a lot, but there is no such method in WP7 :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use XNA's [Guide.BeginShowMessageBox()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940233.aspx) to display a MessageBox with custom buttons. [Here's](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/delivering-message-using) a tutorial on how to use it.

Note that the MessageBoxIcon parameter does not select an icon on WP7, instead it selects the notification sound when the message box is displayed.

**EDIT:**
Oops, didn't read your synchronous requirement before I posted. Maybe you can set a flag to stop whatever you want to prevent from running, and reset it once the user has made a selection.

Comment: Yes, but my biggest problem is that I must use a method that returns only when a button has been clicked. I can use for example a timer to wait until the click event, and continue the program in the timeout event handler if the condition is satisfied, but I cannot figure out how to implement this in one method :(

Comment: AutoResetEvent waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
Guide.BeginShowMessageBox("Version of Windows", "Pick a version of Windows.", new List<string> { "Vista", "Seven" }, 0, MessageBoxIcon.Error, asyncResult =>
                {
                    int? returned = Guide.EndShowMessageBox(asyncResult);
                    waitHandle.Set();
                }, null);
            waitHandle.WaitOne();

this doesn't block the UI thread! Thanx :)

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution

Comment: @Vic: It seems a shame to have to reference Xna to deliver such a basic requirement.  This stems from the requirement for your code to block whilst waiting to a UI event.  Are you absolutely sure this can't be coded any other way?

Comment: The code is complex, it's a multiplatform framework that must implement for example MessageBox.Show() on different platforms in the following way: it must return the result (the text of the pressed button). Two threads and a synchronization of threads is required to accomplish this, because Show() must block the program in order to be able to return with the result. I know it's a shame, but I don't know any other solution, if you know, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I found this when looking for something similar, but wound up just using the built in messagebox. It would certainly give you the ability to have custom buttons.

[Windows Phone 7 Custom Message Box](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2010/10/19/windows-phone-7-custom-message-box.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the Show() part is not satisfied in this solution, only the arbitrary buttons part; if I modify this:

NotificationBox.Show("Exit","Are you sure?",
 new NotificationBoxCommand("Yes", () => { }),
 new NotificationBoxCommand("No", () => { }));

to this:

AutoResetEvent waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
NotificationBox.Show("Exit","Are you sure?",
 new NotificationBoxCommand("Yes", () => { waitHandle.Set(); }),
 new NotificationBoxCommand("No", () => { waitHandle.Set(); }));
waitHandle.WaitOne();

...then I get deadlock, that's my problem :(

Answer (score 1):

Use a Canvas that has everything you want on it. Then just use the visibility property to pop it up..